# Use of variable in the Ajax post

Tags: jquery, cakephp

In my application I am using Ajax post like:

```
$('#fb_contentarea_col3 #fb_contentarea_col1down2 #saveForm').live("click", function() {
  if (!$("#formName").val() == "") {
    if (saveDraft == 'on')
      status = "Incompleted";
    else
      status = "Completed";

    var formname = $("#formName").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/saveForm/",
      async: false,
      data: "formname=" + formname + "&status=" + status,
      success: function(msg) {
        getformid = msg;
        //returned FOrm id is saved in the JQuery variable
      }
      //success
    });
    //ajax

    $("#fb_contentarea_col1down21 div").each(function() {
      alert("Form id " + getformid);
      //alerts me the Form id retrieved
      var checked = "false";
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      var fsize = $("#input" + id + "").width();
      var ftype = $("#input" + id + "").attr('data-attr');
      var finstr = $("#instr" + id + "").text();
      var fname = $("#label" + id + "").clone().html().replace(/<span.*/, '');

      if ($("#label" + id + "> span.req").length > 0)
      {
        checked = "true";
      }

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/saveField",
        async: false,
        data: "sequence_no=" + id + "&name=" + fname + "&type=" + ftype + "&size=" + fsize + "&instr=" + finstr + "&formid=" + getformid + "&required=" + checked,

        success: function(msg) {
            //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg);
        }
        //success
      });
      //ajax
    }
    //for each DIv in mu design page i am saving them as Field
  }
  //if formname exists
}
//saveForm
```

The Form id as returned from the Controller side is saved in the variable getformid correctly, But it is not reflected in the savefield ajax post..And it is saving as 0 only even it alerts as the returned Form id..Please suggest me..

Note ::the question is a reference to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264343/varaibles-inside-success-function-of-ajax-post

In addition I am giving here the Code in my Controller for saveForm

```
function saveForm()
{
  $this->data['Form']['name']=$this->params['form']['formname'];
  $this->data['Form']['created_by']=$this->Session->read('userId');
  $this->data['Form']['status']=$this->params['form']['status'];
  $this->data['Form']['access']="Private";
  $formId=$this->Form->saveForms($this->data);

  $this->set('formId',$formId);
}
```

And my Model saveForms is like

```
function saveForms($data)//design saveForm
{
  $this->data['Form']['name']=$data['Form']['name'];
  $this->data['Form']['created_by']=$data['Form']['created_by'];
  $this->data['Form']['status']=$data['Form']['status'];
  $this->data['Form']['access']=$data['Form']['access'];
  $this->save($this->data);
  return $this->id;//returns the saved Form id to the controller
}
```

And my save_form.ctp in my views folder is like

```
<?php echo $formId;?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're setting `getformid` inside the `success` handler for the AJAX call, but the code that's *using* `getformid` is outside that function.

Never forget that the moment you call something like `$.ajax`, the function returns — immediately, before the AJAX call has completed, and certainly before your `success` function has run.  That's what makes it *asynchronous*.

Thus, any code you want to have executed after the AJAX request is completed has to go inside that `success` function (or in another function that's called from inside `success`, of course).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and pass that around like a parameter.  For instance:

```
function param() {
    this.array = new Array(1);
    this.setValue = function(v) { this.array[0] = v; }
    this.getValue = function() { return this.array[0]; }
}
```

and then in your ajax request. do something like follows:

```
var formId = new param;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/saveForm/",
    async: false,
    data: "formname="+formname+"&status="+status,
    success: function(msg){
          formId.setValue(msg);
    }//success
)};
```

You can then access the value that was set by calling the **getValue()** method of the **formId** variable